# nodejs ReferenceError: oneTimeCode is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having an issue while trying to parse (body-parser) an http post response. I want to use `oneTimeCode` as a variable and evaluate that variable on the server side. I am getting the following error: `ReferenceError: oneTimeCode is not defined` What am I missing?

nodejs

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/verify', function(request, response) {
  if (oneTimeCode == '123456') {
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/index.html');
  } else {
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/otp.html');
  }
 });
app.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/otp.html');
});
https.createServer(options,app).listen(443);
```

otp.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>OTP</title>
<body>
<h1>OTP</h1>
<form action="https://1.2.3.4.com/verify" method="post" target="_blank">
  OTP <input type="text" name="oneTimeCode"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click on the submit button.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is defined _oneTimeCode_ ? Don't you get it from http request ?

Comment: My intent is to have the value of `oneTimeCode` posted back via HTTP...do I need to define that variable on the server side?

Comment: Yes as mentionned in the answer posted by ezakto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oneTimeCode won't be declared as a global variable, it'll be available in request.body.

You can get it like this:

```
app.post('/verify', function(request, response) {
  var oneTimeCode = request.body.oneTimeCode; // Now you have your variable
  if (oneTimeCode == '123456') {
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/index.html');
  } else {
    response.sendFile('/home/ubuntu/otp.html');
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `request.body.oneTimeCode`, `bodyParser` enhances `request` variable